# Display show/hide depending on the combinaion of classes - Javascript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a multi-language registration site. I need to detect if an element has a `class="lng"` which indicates that it will be displayed or hidden, depending on the language selected. (this part already works).

Additionally I need to detect which other class the element with the `lng` class has. So if the combination of classes is `lng` and `en` it will **display** the content in english language and **hide** all the other elements with the `lng` class which do not have an `en` class next to it (`class="lng" class="ru").

I can refactor the html elements so that it has `class="lng en"` if that would have make it easier...

HTML - language selection

```
<input type="image" id="slo" onclick="setLanguage('sl')">
<input type="image" id="ang" onclick="setLanguage('en')">
<input type="image" id="hrv" onclick="setLanguage('hr')">
<input type="image" id="rus" onclick="setLanguage('ru')">
```

HTML example - only one should be displayed, depending on the language selected:

```
<span class="lng" class="sl" class="radioS">Spol: </span>
<span class="lng" class="en" class="radioS">Gender: </span>
<span class="lng" class="hr" class="radioS">Spolov: </span>
<span class="lng" class="ru" class="radioS">секс: </span>
```

Javascript

```
function setLanguage(language) {
    var lngs;
    var i;
    lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");
    console.log(lngs);
    for (var i=0;i<lngs.length;i++){
        if (lngs[i].classList.contains(language) !== language) {
            lngs[i].style.display="none";
        } else {
            lngs[i].style.display="inline-block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I can refactor the html elements so that it has class="lng en" if that would have make it easier..._ You **must** do this because `class` attribute should not be duplicated.

Comment: Classes should be definded in same "class" ie `<span class="lng lng-ls radioS">Spol: </span>`.

Comment: Not sure if this is meant for production use, but if it is, that's not really a great way to go about it. IMO, you shouldn't have all the labels hard-coded, but instead updated them from some sort of label dictionary, when the language changes.

Comment: @DrDoom, just FYI - Russian word "секс" means exactly "sex" as a sexual act, not as a gender. For gender the word is "пол". Don't confuse your Russian users :)

Comment: All right, i'll refactor the elements so they only have one class tag. The idea behind the `en`, `sl`, `hr`, and `ru` classes is that as you click the language flag, it hides all the classes which do not have that language class. And Stalniko, thanks. I'm still working on the site, actual content will be updated later =)

Comment: check out my answer @DrDoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begining make them all invisible then iterate through all inputs and check if the class includes your language:

```js
const lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
    lngs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

init();

function setLanguage(language) {

  debugger
  for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
    if (lngs[i].className.includes(language)) {
      lngs[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      lngs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="image" id="slo" onclick="setLanguage('sl')">
<input type="image" id="ang" onclick="setLanguage('en')">
<input type="image" id="hrv" onclick="setLanguage('hr')">
<input type="image" id="rus" onclick="setLanguage('ru')">


<span class="lng sl radioS">Spol: </span>
<span class="lng en radioS">Gender: </span>
<span class="lng hr radioS">Spolov: </span>
<span class="lng ru radioS">секс: </span>
```

Comment: this might be it. thanks. will let you know if it works.

Comment: I'm getting an error `lngs[i].classList.includes is not a function`

Comment: Pay attention to `class` ,  it's one class now, not 3 : `<span class="lng sl radioS">Spol: </span>` It's more readable to have all the class names under one tag.

Comment: yea, fixed that... now i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setLanguage(language) {
  // var 1
   document
    .getElementsByClassName("lng")
    .forEach(lang => lang.classList.remove('visible'));
   
   // var 2
   document
    .getElementByClassName('visible')
    .forEach(el => el.classList.remove('visible'));
    
  // show target lang  
    document.getElementById(language).classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
.lng {
 display: none;
 }
 
 .visible {
  display: block;
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand this function.... could you please explain what is supposed to be var 1, var 2... Also how would I detect the 2cnd class, which was the question.

Answer (score 0):

simply u can use radio buttons if it is checked that particular matching language will be displayed and others will be hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
    var len = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
      if (len[i].checked == 1) {
        $(".lng." + len[i].id).show();

      } else {
        $(".lng." + len[i].id).hide();

      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lng {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="sl" value="sl" name="lang"> sl
<input type="radio" id="en" value="sl" name="lang"> en
<input type="radio" id="hr" value="sl" name="lang"> hr
<input type="radio" id="ru" value="sl" name="lang"> ru
<br>
<span class="lng sl">Spol: </span>
<span class="lng en" class="en">Gender: </span>
<span class="lng hr" class="hr">Spolov: </span>
<span class="lng ru" class="ru">секс: </span>
```